# unable to check internet connection in iOS 9

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7, internet-connection

I've tested the following in both iOS 8 and iOS 9 devices. it works perfectly fine with iOS 8, but it doesn't work in iOS 9. can anyone please help?

Problem Solved. Solution: put this in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The original code

```
 NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];

if (data) {

    NSLog(@"Device is connected to the internet");

}


else {


    NSLog(@"Device is not connected to the internet");

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the way it doesn't work? Is it possible that App Transport Security is preventing it?

Comment: it doesn't return any action that it shows it has checked the internet connectivity @rikkigibson

Comment: Sounds like it's blocking on the dataWithContentsOfURL call. Make sure the system isn't logging any warnings to the console about that method, and check the docs to see whether it's deprecated.

Comment: my problem is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711990/cloud-kit-access-via-3g-wwan-sometimes-does-not-work-wifi-works-anytime but i don't understand if how to apply NSOperation in the code i have @rikkigibson

Comment: Wow, 18 blank lines, 8 lines of code!

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 has implemented ATS (App Transport Security) and you will need to white list URLs that do not support TLS 1.2 and forward security or allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659981/451475) for more information.